# Question About the Type of an object

Tags: java, object, types

I'm learning java and have a question about object types.

Take the following as an example:

```
class A { }

class B extends A { }

class C {A myObject = new B();}
```

What is the accepted way to describe the type of myObject?

Would you say it is Type A, Type B, or Type A and B?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this? What output do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myObject` is a reference of type `A` (your variable is declared to be of type `A`).

The object itself, which is referred to by `myObject`, is of type `B`. The instance is of type `B`.

It’s a matter of context and focus.
When you use `myObject` in other places you may not know it is an instance of class `B`, only that it is of type `A`.

Comment: The object is not "stored inside" but rather "referred to by" the reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is of type A, since type means operations you can do with it, but it is an instance of B, so all the operations you do will be in B-manner.

Answer (score 1):

`myObject` is field with the declared compile-time type A. At runtime, it will refer to an object of type B.

This distinction between the declared (or compile-time) type of variables and the runtime type of objects is crucial to understanding how polymorphism works in a statically typed language like Java. Some things (like the invocation of overriden methods) are determined by the runtime type, othersy (like the invocation of overloaded or static methods) by the compile-time type.

In general: the declared type determines what you can do with the object, while the runtime type determines how it will behave.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance implies an "is a" relationship - an instance of a subclass **is an** instance of a superclass. In your example, since B extends A, an instance of B is also an instance of A - that's why you can assign a new B to a variable of type A without casting.

The variable `myObject` is of type A, but it refers to an object which is really of type B.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I think I understand this now.